# Proper grammar for plural possession including myself?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I know that when referring to myself and a friend, it is proper to say "John and I", as opposed to "me and John". But when referring to ownership, I can't figure out whether this still applies. For example, "John and I's car" certainly sounds more incorrect than "me and John's car", since "I" cannot be pluralized. What is the proper way of phrasing this?

Comment: What does pluralization have to do with anything?

Comment: By plural I meant more people than myself owning it- and yes, that answers my question, thanks!

Comment: *"I know that when referring to myself and a friend, it is proper to say "John and I", as opposed to "me and John"."* That's not true! There's nothing wrong with "me and John" in the right contexts!